# How to Set Large Range Array Formula and KEEP Relative Row References

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to set a large range in Excel to an array formula. If I loop through it takes too long. If I insert the formula in an adjacent column and then set the `.FormulaArray` to that `.Range.Formula` it takes too long.

I have read of a solution here: [Array formula to VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21926928/array-formula-to-vba)

But this is not working for me.

Current attempt:

```vb
Sub ConvertFormulaToFormulaArray()

'    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    wsData.Range("K2:K27145").FormulaArray = "=IF(H2="""",INDEX($H:$H,MATCH(1,($R$34=$A:$A)*($R$35=$B:$B)*(C2=$C:$C)*(D2=$D:$D),0)),H2)"
'    wsData.Range("K2:K27145").FormulaArray = wsData.Range("J2:J27145").Formula

    wsData.Range("K2:K27145").Copy
    wsData.Range("K2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
'    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Current output:

[image]

Desired output:

[image]

What am I missing here?

---

**Update - Other methods tried**

Takes too long..

```
wsData.Range("K2").FormulaArray = "=IF(H2="""",INDEX($H:$H,MATCH(1,($R$34=$A:$A)*($R$35=$B:$B)*(C2=$C:$C)*(D2=$D:$D),0)),H2)"
wsData.Range("K2:K27145").FillDown
```

Doesn't return correct values..

```
wsData.Range("K2:K27145").FormulaArray = "=IF(H2:H27145="""",INDEX($H:$H,MATCH(1,($R$34=$A:$A)*($R$35=$B:$B)*(C2:C27145=$C:$C)*(D2:D27145=$D:$D),0)),H2:H27145)"
```

Comment: You'll have to use `FormulaArray` to put the formula into the first cell only, then copy and paste or fill down.

Comment: Or, if there should only be one match, use a non-array LOOKUP formula.

Comment: @Rory unfortunately that approach takes way too long, and is not feasible. Is there any reason why the solution in the example I give above would work, but is not working in my WB?

Comment: @Rory and I don't believe I can use a `LOOKUP` because I am finding a value based on multiple columns matching certain criteria

Comment: The solution in that linked post does not work. I'll show you how to use LOOKUP - will post answer in a minute.

Comment: You can look into `.Evaluate`. It does wonders, and you won't have to first put a formula, then fill the clipboard and paste values. It basically is just one line of code. Also you can avoid looking at whole columns to speed things up even more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way to avoid the issue completely by using a non-array formula:

```
Sub ConvertFormulaToFormulaArray()

'    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    wsData.Range("K2:K27145").Formula = "=IF(H2="""",LOOKUP(2,1/($R$34=$A:$A)/($R$35=$B:$B)/(C2=$C:$C)/(D2=$D:$D),$H:$H),H2)"

    wsData.Range("K2:K27145").Copy
    wsData.Range("K2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
'    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

although if you can restrict the ranges being search to the same rows, rather than entire columns, that should help things run faster.

Comment: Dude, massive help, thanks. Takes a bit but MUCH faster than the `FormulaArray`. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
wsData.Range("K2:K27145").FormulaArray = "=IF(H2:H27145="""",INDEX($H:$H,MATCH(1,($R$34=$A:$A)*($R$35=$B:$B)*(C2:C27145=$C:$C)*(D2:27145=$D:$D),0)),H2:H27145)"
```

Comment: I don't believe that will return the correct results.

Comment: This returns the correct `H` values, but returns `#N/A` for the `INDEX/MATCH` values.